# Custom block and menu caching

Tags: blocks, caching

I have a custom block building a menu.
The cache works fine until a menu item is enabled/disabled in the menu edit, e.g.

admin/structure/menu/manage/main
toggle the enabled checkbox and save.

The block does not reflect changes until the cache is cleared.

I have:

```
            '#cache' => [
                'tags' => [
                    'node_list'
                ],
                'contexts' => [
                    'url.path',
                ],
            ],
```

which picks up the url / menu text changes and also makes sure the block is valid for each node it is on [i.e. not showing the same block content on every node, but this node's version].

What tag do I need to make sure the cache is invalidated when menu item:enabled is toggled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the cache tag of the menu, in this case the main menu:

```
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => [
      'config:system.menu.main',
      ...
```

Comment: Hi @4k4, thank you for the answer. I had tried a few variations of that tag, for example, the last attempt I had was: config:system:menu.main - is there somewhere I can get the patterns for common tags? I looked at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-tags and saw 'thing:identifier', but did not make the leap to the correct tag format.

Comment: Enable [debugging of cacheable reponses](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/responses/cacheableresponseinterface#debugging) and check the response headers in the browser F12 tools. You could for example place a core menu block on the page and see the cache tags added by this block.